Windows DNS Server - different response per subnet
I've recently deployed three new Windows Server DCs in a new subnet. Unfortunately I came across this problem, where the new DCs won't respond (at least properly) to DNS requests made by clients on the old subnet. Wireshark shows an immediate response to my DNS requests but instead of getting the IP the DCs seem to forward my request to "a.root-servers-net" and answer with "Non-existent domain". (even requesting with FQDN)
Requesting the same hostnames in their own subnet works just fine.
Every client is on the same domain.
For now it works fine because the old DCs are still running (and replying to both subnets correctly) and replicating properly but eventually we want to retire them.

DNS (forward) doesn't know anything about subnets, request-originations or zones on other servers. When your DNS is forwarding your request to (whatever forwarder you are using), the zone your request aims at, is not on that server. Triple check your DNS servers zones (and your forwardings).
